# How protect styles when embedding widget in unknown sites?

Tags: html, css

Let's say we build a news site SupaNews, and we would like to allow people to embed news stream in their sites.

The first thing that comes to mind is that every CSS rule should be prefixed with unique prefix `supanews`

```
<div class="supanews">
  <ul class="supanews-list">
    <li class="supanews-item">Zerg found on Tarsonis!</li>
    <li class="supanews-item">Protoss mothersip noticed in Koprulu sector</li>
  </ul>
<div>
```

But, the Elements still inherit styles from the main site and it would broke the markup. Is there any way to prevent that? Maybe some special heavy `reset.css` that would be applied to `.supanews` section?

Also, I wonder if it would be possible to avoid adding prefix to every CSS rule, and somehow tell the browser that everything inside of `.supanews` is kinda scoped? The HTML would look like code below, and the browser should figure out that `.list` inside of `.supanews` should not inherit same rules as `.list` from the outer HTML:

```
<div class="supanews">
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="item">Zerg found on Tarsonis!</li>
    <li class="item">Protoss mothersip noticed in Koprulu sector</li>
  </ul>
<div>
```

It's also possible to use `iframe`, it would give the perfect isolation but I would like to explore other ways. It's ok if it would work only in let's say 97% of sites.

Comment: It is up to the person embedding the html into their site to style it properly otherwise anything you do to reset styles will upset their site if they use the same classes

Comment: @Pete yes, but if you care about promotion and marketing it's better to not shift that responsibility on end users :)

Comment: Then your only option is to make them embed an iframe, that way you have total control of styles and they will not be affected by the site styles, but bear in mind, as a developer, I would not use an api where I didn't have full control of how the content was styled - most decent companies let you style the content how you want as long as you use their logo somewhere in your site

Comment: Shadow DOM comes to my mind, but I don't know if it's applicable to third party content.

Comment: As Pete said your only option is most likely to use an iframe if you want *full* control of how the embedded content looks like. Most embedded rich-styled third party widgets are iframes, generally speaking.

Comment: Provide an embeddable iframe widget for those that don’t mind how the widget looks and provide an API for those users that just want to use your news feeds and style it how they want. As somebody else mentioned you can also use the Shadow DOM to isolate your styles. That’s how a lot of browser extensions work.

Comment: Just prefix your css classes with supanews, reset whatever you need under supanews container. This has nothing to do with promotion or marketing, you can only package your widget to look a certain way but you cannot control other website's styles so overriding might occur and if it does then they can take care of it. As long as you prefix your stuff, chances of overriding are slim. Other site might actually want to override your styles because it doesn't fit their site, you can't please everyone